# How can I recover from a world wipe due to the Technic Pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I've been using the Technic Pack launcher to play the Technic Pack for the last few days. The launcher said there was an update for Sprout or something like that, and I pressed the *OK* button.

When I went into my world, all the mod items were missing: in my chests, in my inventory, and even placed blocks. I tried recovering from the backup, but the saves folder wasn't there.

I've lost probably 20 hours of work! What can I do?

Comment: I have had problems when the launcher could not connect forcing me to play in offline mode. You did log in with your minecraft account right? EDIT: My problem was my inventory was empty, the world was as I left it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem with various updates to Technic. There's nothing you can do.

As suggested, always make sure you have a backup before updating. Also, I would recommend checking the Update page of the technic pack before updating. Some updates will result in current items to change ID's, or simply disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I recovered my world.

Here's how it goes:

1. Click the home button (the one with the Windows logo on the bottom left) and type `%appdata%`
2. It should show up with a folder called "Roaming". Click this.
3. Find ".techniclauncher" (If you cannot open it, download WinRar)
4. Click the "tekkit" folder
5. Click "saves"
6. Right click with your mouse
7. Click "Properties"
8. Find the "Previous Versions" tab.
9. Find the name of your world
10. Drag this file to the ORIGINAL saves folder, the one without your world on it.
11. Launch game

Comment: This only works if you have Shadow Volume Copies, pretty much like when you have Ransomware